# Does this type of differential equation have a name?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology, dirac-delta

Does a differential equation of the form:
$$y''(x)+\delta(x)y=Ay$$
where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac Delta function and $A$ is a constant have a specific name?

Comment: Although I have not yet found a formal name for it, if you want to look it up searching for 'Dirac delta potential' is a good place to start https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential#Single_delta_potential